# pass array (undetermined size) with url in php

Tags: php, arrays, get

I have php file that generate result from user input. The result are not equals. I mean sometimes it generate 3 result and sometimes it generate 5 or 4 or 2 result.
First, I define an array variable to store these result:

```
$resultcount = 0;
$result=array();
while(!feof($fpout3)) 
{
    $row = fgets($fpout3);
    if (!$row) {continue;}
    $element = preg_split("/\t/", $row);        
    $page = $element[0];
    $queryName = $element[1];
    $target_name = $element[7];
    $var_target = $page."\t".$element[1]."\t".$element[2];
    if(count($element) != 1) 
    {
        if($i < 10) 
        {
            echo "<tr align='center'><td align=left><input type='checkbox' id='checkedSeq' name='target[]' value='$var_target'>$target_name</td></tr>";
            fwrite($fp, "$var_target\n");

            // fill $result array
            $resultcount++;
            $result[$resultcount]=$target_name;
            //////////////////////
        }                   
    }
}
```

I want to send the $result array with url link to save it in the database:
I already send other variables with the url and now want to pass the $result array with them:

```
echo "<form action='saveResult.php?searchType=$searchType&querySeq=$querySeq&patientIDarray=$patientIDarray&expect=$expect&wordSize=$wordSize' method='post' target='_blank' onsubmit=\"return checkform(this);\">";
echo "<input type='submit' value='Save Result'>";
echo "</form>";
```

saveResult.php:

```
<?php
$searchType = (empty($_GET['searchType'])) ? '' : $_GET['searchType'];
$querySeq = (empty($_GET['querySeq'])) ? '' : $_GET['querySeq'];
$patientIDarray = (empty($_GET['patientIDarray'])) ? '' : $_GET['patientIDarray'];
$QueryDate = date("Y-m-d");
$expect=(empty($_GET['expect'])) ? 10 : $_GET['expect'];
$wordSize = (empty($_GET['wordSize'])) ? '' : $_GET['wordSize'];

$serverName = "Alaa";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"i2b2blast", "UID"=>"i2b2blast", "PWD"=>"demouser");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Result Saved.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO BlastQueryDim (QuerySeq, DatabaseName, WordSize, ExpectThreshold, QueryDate) VALUES ('$querySeq', '$patientIDarray', '$wordSize', '$expect', '$QueryDate')";

$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql);
if( $stmt === false ) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
echo "<script>
alert('Result Saved');
</script>";
?>
```

**My question: How to pass $result array with the url? and how to get each index in the other php "saveResult"?**

Thanks,

**Edit1:**

I type:

```
    echo "<form action='saveResult.php?searchType=$searchType&querySeq=$querySeq&patientIDarray=$patientIDarray&expect=$expect&wordSize=$wordSize' method='post' target='_blank' onsubmit=\"return checkform(this);\">";
foreach ($result as $resultcount => $target_name)
echo "<input type='hidden' name='result[$resultcount]' value='$target_name'/>";
echo "<input type='submit' value='Save Result'>";
echo "</form>";
```

in saveResult.php, i type:

```
$result = empty($_POST['result']) ? array() : $_POST['result'];
```

and try to echo it and it displays: 'Array' which means that it recieve it as an empty!

**Edit 2:**
I solve the problem by using:

```
$result = json_encode($_POST['result'], true); 
echo $result;
```

Now, the output of echo is:

```
{"1":"gi|1786181|gb|AE000111|ECAE000111","2":"gi|1786250|gb|AE000117|ECAE000117"}
```

How can I insert the second cell of each row in the database?
I want to insert 'gi|1786181|gb|AE000111|ECAE000111' in a row 
and insert 'gi|1786250|gb|AE000117|ECAE000117' in another row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note, if you go "echo $_POST['result']", you will always return "Array". You need to do is "print_r", to dump that array...

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['result'])) {

    $sql = null;

    foreach ($_POST['result'] as $resultcount => $target_name) {
        echo $resultcount . " -> " .$target_name;
        //$sql .= "INSERT INTO table (resultcount, target) VALUES (...);";
    }

    if($sql) {
        sqlsrv_query(....);
    }

}
```

I will tip you again: Careful with those sql, maybe implements PDO to bind values.

Comment: OMG. it is working like that. Many thanks to you. I will try inserting now. if it does not work i will type here the problem.

Comment: Thanks, nice jobs!

Comment: Great! Great! Great!

Answer (score 1):

To pass the `$result` array when the form is submitted, just create hidden inputs like this:

```
echo "<form action='saveResult.php?searchType=$searchType&querySeq=$querySeq&patientIDarray=$patientIDarray&expect=$expect&wordSize=$wordSize' method='post' target='_blank' onsubmit=\"return checkform(this);\">";

foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='result[$key]' value='$value'/>";
}

echo "<input type='submit' value='Save Result'>";
echo "</form>";
```

And in the `saveResult.php` get the result like this:

```
$result = empty($_POST['result']) ? array() : $_POST['result'];
```

Comment: It sounds good. I will try it. What about the insert query? Just put: '$result'?

Comment: For insert in database you can store like JSON, use `json_encode($result)`, and when select decode to array using `$result = json_decode($json, true)`. I saw that you use Microsoft SQL Server, I do not know this database, if it does not have a JSON type for column you can use a TEXT type or similar.

Comment: Do you mean I can't use: "insert into TABLE (WordSize, ExpectThreshold, QueryDate, result) VALUES ('$wordSize', '$expect', '$QueryDate', '$result')"? I want to save each result in a row.

Comment: `$result` is a array, to save a array in a row you can convert the array to a json string, `$result_json = json_encode($result)`, so you can use: `insert into TABLE (WordSize, ExpectThreshold, QueryDate, result) VALUES ('$wordSize', '$expect', '$QueryDate', '$result_json')`

Comment: No i want to save each result in a separate row

Comment: So, just use a `foreach ($result as $resultcount => $target_name)` and for each result insert a row in the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can send a _post as array more useful:

```
echo "<form action='saveResult.php?searchType=$searchType&querySeq=$querySeq&patientIDarray=$patientIDarray&expect=$expect&wordSize=$wordSize' method='post' target='_blank' onsubmit=\"return checkform(this);\">";
// here you is the "solution"
foreach($result as $id => $name){
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='result[".$id."]' value='".$name."'>";
}
echo "<input type='submit' value='Save Result'>";
echo "</form>";
```

Then in saveResult.php, you have now a $_POST['result'] as an array.

Tip: Be careful with your sql statement to avoid injections.

**Edit**

You now is receiving a array, now if you can retrieve that info, you just use json_encode or add a foreach again in saveResult.php:

```
foreach($result as $resultcount => $target_name){
    // Here, can ho your statement or sql
}
```

Comment: Add the brackets after the foreach. In saveResult.php, try print_r($result);

Comment: where to add the brackets exactly?

Comment: Before your input hidden.

Comment: it recieve it as empty. I solve it with using: $result = json_encode($_POST['result'], true); see edited post pleas. I have another question.